# How do I know whether an arbitrary header name is valid as a request header, content header, or neither?

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

Consider this code:

```
if (request.Headers.Contains(headerName))
    ...
```

where `request` is an instance of [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage). `headerName` is fairly arbitrary; let's assume it's coming from user input. If its value happens to be `"Content-Type"`, an exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

How exactly do I "make sure" of this? The `Headers` collection internally knows which header names are allowed, and this list is different for `request.Headers` than it is for `request.Content.Headers`. It seems I have 2 options for validating an arbitrary string:

1. Keep my own "whitelist" to validate against, based on the BCL documentation or source code.
2. Use try/catch logic.

Neither of these approaches seems ideal. Is there a way to leverage the knowledge already contained in `System.Net.Http` to perform this validation?

Comment: Are you asking this w.r.t. your library Flurl? If so, you might want to mention that this is library code. Option 1, i.e. the whitelist, would make perfect sense for some user-facing app imho.

Comment: It is, but whether it's a library or user-facing app isn't relevant. In either case the whitelist would probably be preferable to try/catch, but still less than ideal considering it requires me to duplicate rules already contained in System.Net.Http (and keep them in sync with future versions). There doesn't appear to be a `TryContains` or `IsValidName` or anything along those lines to help me guard against bumping into that exception.

Comment: I beg to differ. Giving "feedback" to calling code is different than giving feedback to some user (on the UI). The other problem is what you mention yourself - maintenance of your whitelist: in library code, all users of your library depend on it which means that number of apps, and releasing updates to it is not so straightforward.

Comment: I don't want to keep debating this here but I think you're missing the point of my question. It's not about providing feedback, it's about safeguarding against an exception without duplicating rules internal to the library that's throwing them.

Comment: Alright, on topic then: what's the problem with try/catch?